# flex context menu clipboard item clear

Tags: actionscript-3, flex3, air

I am using context menu using the code given below in a flex air application. For me all Context Menu Clipboard Items are working fine except "clear".

Plese suggest me where I am wrong.

```
var cMenu:ContextMenu = createContextMenu();

private function createContextMenu():ContextMenu
{               
        var editContextMenu:ContextMenu = new ContextMenu();
        editContextMenu.hideBuiltInItems();                     
        editContextMenu.clipboardMenu = true;
        editContextMenu.clipboardItems.cut = true;
        editContextMenu.clipboardItems.copy = true;
        editContextMenu.clipboardItems.paste = true;

         //NOT WORKING
         editContextMenu.clipboardItems.clear = true;

        return editContextMenu
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "clear"
when I select some text then go for delete in context menu. It is not deleting the slelcted text.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that the object you are trying to clear cannot be cleared.
Quote from the livedocs

> Enables or disables the 'Delete' or 'Clear' item on the clipboard menu. This should be enabled only if an object that can be cleared is selected.